# How can I save timestamps without quotation marks to an Excel sheet using pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, python-datetime

I am trying to save two time stamps into an excel sheet column. This is the code that I am using to generate the time stamps.

```
start_timestamp = pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0)).__str__()
end_timestamp = pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0)).__str__()

xls2[column_name][row_number] = start_timestamp
xls2[column_name][row_number] = end_timestamp
```

However, when I save the excel sheet. I get the dates in this format `'2023-06-01 00:00:00`
I want it in `2023-06-01 08:05:00`

I was using pandas library to generate the timestamp. And the format. However, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is producing the string format by using `.__str__()`. Also `datetime` is not needed. You can just use:

```
start_timestamp = pd.Timestamp(2023, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0)
end_timestamp = pd.Timestamp(2023, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0)
```